# Create a view that shows entries only if they are 120 days from a date column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a list that tracks users loss date from the organization. This date is assigned from they day the arrive and are entered into the list (loss date). I am trying to create a view that would display individuals that are due to depart the organization in that 120 day window. The view would need to display the individuals from the moment they are 6 months (120 days) out until they day they leave (loss date). I am trying to avoid using Now and Today if at all possible. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the SharePoint online, there is no OOB way to filter the view between two dates range, we could only use [Today] or valid date, such as 12/22/2020, specific column values is not supported.

If you are in the SharePoint on-premise, we could use Date filter web part to achieve this, for more information, please refer to:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/filter-list-using-date-range-of-a-column-in-sharepoint/